# Purpose of :: before include module in ruby

Tags: ruby, module, include

What is the different between the following two include statements:

```
include ::Module1:Module2
```

and

```
include Module1::Module2
```

Both worked in my case. But, I just wonder which one is better (or both are totally fine).

Comment: SymbolHound is your friend: http://symbolhound.com/?q=ruby+%3A%3A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `::Module1::Module2` would be referencing the top-level namespace, rather than the relative namespace of where the statement is being executed.

This is useful in scenarios where you're trying to reference a top-level module within another module, like so:

```
class YourClass
end

module YourModule
  class YourClass
  end

  def self.new_outer_class
    ::YourClass.new
  end

  def self.new_inner_class
    YourClass.new
  end
end
```

With the above setup, calling `#new_outer_class` would actually instantiate the instance of `YourClass` class defined outside of `YourModule`, whereas calling `#new_inner_class` would instantiate `YourModule::YourClass` since it's relative to and called within `YourModule`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Does that mean in my case both are interchangeable?

Comment: In your specific case, they would be effectively achieving the same result. However, using `::Module1::Module2` would break the moment another namespace level is added on top of `Module1`.